# fill 3 listview that's in separate tabs in a tabhost

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I have 3 tabs(activities) in my `tabhost`  and each tab has one listview.
How can I fill each `listview` when switching from one to another tab?

Comment: Are you using tabhost with activities? Then this question makes no sense. Simply set adapter for those listviews in corresponding activity. (for fragments too)

Comment: i place in each tab just a listview and I don't now where should I place my code until that works when switch a tab

Comment: [This Link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)  or [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/simple-android-tabhost-and-tabwidget-example.html)  will help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tabhost and listview, I'd recommend using ViewPager that contains RecyclerView with your elements, bundled with [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). These elements work perfectly together and you can fill your list in [OnPageSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) callback from viewpager.